# Diagonalization of a complex hermitian matrix in c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I need to find a piece of code that will diagonalize a complex hermitian matrix. The size I'm looking at will be ranging from 3x3 to 30x30. Any help would be great, I'm a little new to c++. Please could you post links to the code rather than a description of where to find it if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple google search would have given the answer. Nonetheless you can start with

1. http://www.netlib.org/lapack++/
2. http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/
3. http://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/personalhomes/globes/3x3/
4. http://www.nrbook.com/empanel/

Comment: I've been searching all day but given that I don't have much experience with C++ I was struggling to find what I was looking for. But thanks

Comment: @Marcus You can accept the answer if you found what you were looking for